# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster._k_means' scikit-learn 0.22 vs 0.22.1

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I ran into an issue that when loading a pickled model (developed in 0.22 scikit-learn), there is no error and no warning.

However, when loading the same model in 0.22.1, it threw out warnings and a module not found error. For the warning, I can see from the release notes of 0.22.1 this has been a new feature introduced in 0.22.1. But I could not find any info related to the module not found error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster._k_means'
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem too. One would be tempted to change `_k_means` to `_kmeans` but I'm not sure of the consequences..

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it may be a version issue.
I have had the same problem and solved it by uninstalling scikit and install and older version (0.22).

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install scikit-learn==0.22
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because apparently when you name your file `sklearn.py` the library will bug out and not import correctly.  Renaming the file to `sklearn_approach.py` fixed my issue.